# MVC Networking Swift

Tags: swift

I have this Networking class that i declared in the Model .

```
class Networking {
    func response (url : String ) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: urlPathCompletionHandler(data:response:error:)).resume()
    }

    func urlPathCompletionHandler (data : Data?  , response: URLResponse? , error: Error? ) {
        guard let data = data else {return }
        do {
            let jsondecoder = JSONDecoder()
        }catch {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller . I have an array of users i declared and i want the controller to call from the Model Networking class instead of doing the networking inside the controller. This is part of my controller:

```
var users = [Users]()
var networking : Networking()
@IBOutlet weak var tableview : UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self

}
func getFromModel() {
  var vm = networking.response()
```

}

I want a way of calling the networking class and return an array of users that i can set to the users array above and use it to populate the table view . If i wanted to do that inside the controller it would easy but i am not sure how i can return an array of users from the Model Networking class .

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your Network class like this:

```swift
class Networking {
    func response<T: Codable>(url: String, completion: ((T) -> Void)?) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            self.urlPathCompletionHandler(data: data, response: response, error: error, completion: completion)
        }).resume()
    }

    func urlPathCompletionHandler<T: Codable>(data : Data?  , response: URLResponse? , error: Error?, completion:   ((T) -> Void)?) {
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let jsondecoder = JSONDecoder()
            // Pseudo Code to decode users
            completion?(decodedObject)
        } catch {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```swift
func getFromModel() {
    networking.response(url: <#T##String#>) { (users: [User]) in
        self.users = users
    }
}
```

Comment: But now the Networking class only supports downloading and decoding User objects.

Comment: Updated using generics.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a few thoughts:

1. Your `response` method is performing an asynchronous network request, so you need to give it a completion handler parameter. So, I might suggest something like:

   ```
   class Networking {
       enum NetworkingError: Error {
           case invalidURL
           case failed(Data?, URLResponse?)
       }

       private let parsingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".parsing")

       // response method to handle network stuff

       func responseData(_ string: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
           guard let url = URL(string: string) else {
               completion(.failure(NetworkingError.invalidURL))
               return
           }

           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   if let error = error {
                       completion(.failure(error))
                       return
                   }

                   guard
                       let responseData = data,
                       let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                       200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
                   else {
                       completion(.failure(NetworkingError.failed(data, response)))
                       return
                   }

                   completion(.success(responseData))
               }
           }.resume()
       }

       // response method to handle the JSON parsing

       func response<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type, from string: String, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
           responseData(string) { result in
               switch result {
               case .failure(let error):
                   completion(.failure(error))

               case .success(let data):
                   self.parsingQueue.async {
                       do {
                           let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               completion(.success(responseObject))
                           }
                       } catch let parseError {
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               completion(.failure(parseError))
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. This obviously assumes that you have some Codable types. For example, it’s common for an API to have some common structure in its responses:

   ```
   struct ResponseObject<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
       let code: Int
       let message: String?
       let data: T?
   }
   ```

   And maybe the `User` is like so:

   ```
   struct User: Decodable {
       let id: String
       let name: String
   }
   ```
3. Then `getFromModel` (perhaps better called `getFromRepository` or something like that) could parse it with:

   ```
   networking.response(of: ResponseObject<[User]>.self, from: urlString) { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)

       case .success(let responseObject):
           let users = responseObject.data
           // do something with users
       }
   }
   ```
4. For what it’s worth, if you didn’t want to write your own networking code, you could use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), and then `getFromModel` would do:

   ```
   AF.request(urlString).responseDecodable(of: ResponseObject<[User]>.self) { response in
       switch response.result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error)

       case .success(let responseObject):
           let users = responseObject.data
       }
   }
   ```

Now, clearly the model types are likely to be different in your example, but you didn’t share what your JSON looked like, so I had to guess, but hopefully the above illustrates the general idea. Make a generic-based network API and give it a completion handler for its asynchronous responses.